# Добавить проверку в таблицу в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Увидел этот код, не понимаю как его перевести в *PostgreSQL.* То есть точно такой же запрос только на *PostgreSQL.* Я новичок, помогите разобраться, заранее спасибо.

```sql
ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK (test LIKE '[AP]');
```

Comment: Это добавляет в структуру таблицы ограничение, которое не позволит вставить новую запись или изменить существующую так, что для неё указанное условие неверно. В постгрессе пишется точно так же, только надо еще присвоить ограничению имя.

Comment: @Akina Можете написать где присвоить ограничению имя и как правильней сделать для PostgreSQL?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-alter.html#DDL-ALTER-ADDING-A-CONSTRAINT

Comment: @Akina Напишете ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо так:

```sql
ALTER TABLE t ADD CHECK (test LIKE '[AP]');
```

Либо так:

```sql
ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT t_cstrt CHECK (test LIKE '[AP]');
```